# Program in Java never finishes

Tags: java, infinite-loop

I'm only in a beginner Java course in high school so I'm just learning Java. Here is my program

```
public static void CubeRoot(double number, double guess)
{
    double r = number;
    double a = guess;
    double b = 0;
    double goal = Math.pow(number,.333333333333);
    while (Math.round(b * 10000) / 10000 != Math.round(goal * 10000) / 10000)
    {
        b = ((1/3)*((r/(a*a))+(2*a)));
        b = a;
    }
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

I'm trying to get an approximation of the cube root of 10.6 using the Newton-Raphson method. The problem is that the program runs but never prints anything out.

Comment: Add a print inside the loop so you can see what is happening to `b`. Also the RHS of your while is a constant, so better off calculating that once and reusing it.

Comment: Floating-point numerics are tricky, and strict equality in a situation like this is not what you should check for. Instead, you should terminate the loop when the approximation is within some range of the target.

Comment: @Pointy Do you mean something like this?                          while (b != goal + .0001 || b != goal - .0001)
  {
   b = ((1.0/3.0)*((r/(a*a))+(2*a)));
   a = b;
  }

Comment: Just subtract the approximation from the goal and take the absolute value, and then compare that to your "close enough" value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It loops forever because you assign one value to `b`, and then overwrite it with `a`. That means that whenever the loop starts, `b` will have the same value as `a`'s initial value.

From looking at the Newton-Raphson algorithm, I think what you actually want is

```
b = ((1.0/3.0)*((r/(a*a))+(2*a)));
a = b;
```

Which will set `a` equal to the new value of `b` that you just calculated, so that it can be used in the next iteration. You should also use `1.0/3.0` instead of `1/3`. Integer division truncates the result, so `1/3` equals `0`, not `0.33` like you want.

Comment: I would also suggest replacing (1/3) with (1.0/3.0) to avoid the integer division.

Comment: @JimLewis Good call. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your inner loop since after the second iteration if the break condition is not met you will loop forever since

`b = ((1/3)*((r/(a*a))+(2*a)));
b = a;`

will always evaluate to the same answer since `a` is never changing. Also, as stated above, assigning `b=a` will undo the first calculation. But either way, your internal logic is preventing the loop from evaluating to true.